# Every Time Return Old Data in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using PHP WebService.

After update entry it return old data again.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += jobseeker;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(string.Format("http://ec2-54-41-130-155.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/board/api/abc.php?func=myaccount&user_id={0}", Empid)));
```

Comment: Probably its not updating . where is your completed event?

Comment: I get Response From Server Entry Is Update.When I check on Website Entry is Updated.But When I again hit From the App it pick Old Data rather then New Data.  Same Thing Happened In IOS But as when i am using the GET method in request like ~[request setHttpMethod:@"GET"].i have resolved the same by changing the GET to POSt .Here how can i specify the POST Method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to automatic caching of results by `WebClient`. To overcome this, use a `cache buster`. That is, add a random string as `url parameter` to your `url`.

Hence, the `Uri` will be

```
Uri _uri = new Uri("APIURL/abc.php?func=myaccount&user_id={0}&cachebust=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

I have experienced the same caching when I connected my app to my WAMP server.